# Will OBIEE RPD work if all the tables in physical layer are not present in database?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, obiee

Here's a scenario:
Say I have a report which touches 10 tables in the physical layer. There are 100 tables in the physical layer of the RPD. Now I am changing the connection pool in the physical layer to point it to a different database/data-source. This new database has only those 10 tables in it (with the exact same structure as that in the previous database), which my report is using, but the rest of the 90 tables from the connection pool are not present.
Will my report work after this repointing to a different database/data-source? Or do I have to create all those 100 tables in the new database before trying to run my report?
I am just changing the connection pool in the RPD. Otherwise the everything in the RPD remains unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will. You will start seeing errors as soon as you reference something which doesn't exist.

Comment: So as long as I don't refer the tables that don't it should be fine right?

Comment: Yes. Only problem could be bad RPD design which forces join inclusion but that's something that would have had to be actively messed up.

Comment: Thanx a lot Chris :)